# Prove that for any positive integer $n$, $n > 1$, $2^{1/n}$ is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I think its proof by contradiction. 
Let $2^{\frac{1}{n}}$ be rational. 
Then $2^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{p}{q}$ where $p, q$ are integers and the fraction is in lowest terms. 
Then $2 = {(\frac{p}{q})}^n$ and $2q^n=p^n$. So we know that $p^n$ must be even. My intuition tells me that I should try to prove $q^n$ also even so I can contradict the claim that the fraction is in lowest terms, but I don't know a way to do that. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Write $p=2p'$ and divide by $2$ the equality $2q^n=2^np'^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of proving that $q^n$ is even, you should first prove that $p$ is even.

Then, if $p$ is even, you can see that $q^n = \frac{p^n}{2}$ and you can show that $q^n$ must be even because $p=2k$.

Then, you show that $q$ is even, and you arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: So we prove $p$ is even by using the theorem that the nth root of an even integer is even?

Comment: @shoestringfries Is there such a theorem? I mean, it can't be the way you wrote it, since $\sqrt{2}$ is not even, because it's not even an integer...

Comment: Is it the nth positive integer root of an even integer is even?

Comment: Then what theorem should I use to prove $p$ is even from $p^n$?

Comment: @shoestringfries If $p^n$ is even, then $p$ is even. More generally, if $q\mid p^n$ for a prime $q$, then $q\mid p$. This follows from [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Comment: @shoestringfries You don't need to use a theorem. You can use your own mathematical brain to figure it out. The best way to do it is by contraposition, i.e. instead of showing that if $p^n$ is even, then $p$ is even, you show that if $p$ is not even, then $p^n$ is not even.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$2q^n = p^n$.

Let
$v(m)$
be the exponent
of the largest power of $2$
that divides $m$,
so
$2^{v(m)} \mid m$
and
$2^{v(m)+1} \not \mid m
$.

Then,
since
$v(a^n) = nv(a)$, we must have
$1+nv(q)=nv(p)$,
or
$1
=n(v(p)-v(q)) 
$.

But this is impossible,
since
$n(v(p)-v(q))$
is either $0$
(if $v(p) = v(q)$)
or a non-zero multiple of $n$
(if $v(p) \ne v(q)$).
In either case,
it can not be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: If $2^{1/n}=\frac{p}{q}$ so $2q^n=p^n$, i.e., $q^n+q^n=p^n$. If $n>2$ this is a contradiction by Fermat's Last Theorem.