# Rational Roots Theorem corollary and piano tuning: $\big(\frac{a}{b}\big)^n \neq 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, music-theory

I'm trying to understand why pianos "can't be tuned" and am looking for a proof of a corollary of the rational roots theorem found here (looking for proof not by contradiction):
https://youtu.be/1Hqm0dYKUx4?t=171

It's stated:

For any integers $a, b$ and $n$ with $n > 1$ then $\big(\frac{a}{b}\big)^n \neq 2$

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1477179/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1451172/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1451172/42969  – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cbig(%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%5Cbig)%5En%20%5Cneq%202%24&p=1)

Comment: Thanks for finding those links. Any chance of a not proof by contradiction?

Comment: @chankonabe Use the same proofs to show that an integer power $\ge 1$  of a non-integer fraction remains a non-integer (so never $= 2)$